# Google Cloud kubernetes engine external ip

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have mongodb hosted in Mongo Atlas. There for security reasons I have whitelisted some IPs, that can access it.

Now that I have set up kubernetes cluster in google cloud, how can I make it able to access this mongodb service since I don't have clear IP for my cluster/swarm instances that get spawned on demand.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get static IPs with GKE. You need to use a NAT gateway. You can [configure a GCE VM to act as your NAT gateway](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#natgateway) for all outbound traffic from your cluster.

There have been multiple requests for a GCP native NAT feature and I believe that feature is on the way. In the meantime, a GCE VM acting as a NAT gateway is your best bet

**EDIT** you can now use [Google Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/using-nat) to assign a single (or multiple) static IPs to your cluster (or other Google resources)

Comment: For today, you've tamed the jungle that is Google Cloud documentation.